How to ignore WHERE in a SQL statement
I have a simple statement:
SELECT *  
FROM Articles 
WHERE Category = @category

When the @category is 0 or null, I need the WHERE condition to be ignored and SQL select all articles

Why an IF statement? Have you considered using OR logic in the WHERE clause?

What you ask is called a catch-all query and is not a good idea in general, resulting in bad execution plans. Why do you want it in the first place?

WHERE (Category = @category OR @category = 0) maybe? Not sure why you thought an IF statement was allowed in the middle of another statement.

WHERE Category = @category or @category = 0 or @category is null

This article explains the problem with such catch-all queries and ways to avoid bad performance. You may have to add OPTION(RECOMPILE) to that query and pay the cost of always recompiling instead of reusing execution plans

BTW, are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (You can delete the unrelated tag.)

@jarlh sqlserver

The syntax is T-SQL, although all databases would have the same issues with catch-all queries

@Reza245 you didn't explain why you need this catch-all query yet. ORMs and client-side query builders can generate parameterized queries without the unwanted parameters.

but when the @category is null... that just repeats the second paragraph. Why do you want this at all? If you use EF, you can simply not add the Where call if a parameter is null, eg if (category !=null) { query=query.Where(a=>a.Category==category); } or if (category >0) { query=query.Where(a=>a.Category==category); }

Try this out https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=c0b9f104-3ff4-4232-8656-59dd6e0cd43d     -- change line 15 to mess with it

Although catch-all query is not a good idea, still you can consider using 'OR' in 'WHERE` clause

The correct solution to this is to generate the query on the client if possible and just not include the clause if the parameter is empty. If LINQ is used, eg with EF Core, it's easy to build a query one part at a time :
var query=context.Articles.AsQueryable();
if(categoryId>0)
{
    query=query.Where(a=>a.CategoryId=categoryId);
}

In SQL, there's no way to compare a NULL with any other value, even NULL, so IS NULL needs to be used.
SELECT *  
FROM Articles 
WHERE (Category = @category OR @category IS NULL or @category=0)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

The OPTION (RECOMPILE) part is important. Databases compile queries into execution plans and reuse them instead of recompiling all the time. This saves a lot of time and memory, especially on busy systems. Without OPTION(RECOMPILE) the server will reuse the same execution plan that was generated on the first call. If @category is null, that execution plan will scan the entire table instead of using any indexes that cover Category
This should NOT be used, because it prevents the use of indexes entirely :
ISNULL(Category,0)=ISNULL(@category,0)

Indexes are created from the stored values and can't be used to speed up filtering using function results.

So I would structure it like this
IF @category = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Category = @category
END

EDIT:
You could also use a case expression as so:
select *
from Articles
where category = (
    case when @category= 0 then @category end
)


by this way I would have to write the statement twice, once with WHERE, once without, and it's not a right way

The second query will not work as expected.

There's no way to fix this with CASE. NULL can't be compared with NULL so IS NULL must be used. The clauses in the comments are the only option that works and doesn't force a full table scan

@PanagiotisKanavos CASE WHEN @category= 0 THEN @category ELSE category END should work, but that's mor of an ugly hack than a real solution ;-)

@BillTürstandswithUkraine it doesn't handle NULL. category = NULL always fails

@PanagiotisKanavos if category can be NULL it would fail, you're correct.
